# How to display an input from a HTML textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to receive an integer from my html input field, then run a javascript file that displays what I've just submitted.

What am I missing?

HTML:

```
 <body>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/server_browse.js"></script>
        <p>Search the Database</p>
        <p>Enter the PO number:</p>

        <form id="PO" action="js/server_browse.js">
            PO:
            <input name="entry" type="number">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

Separate javascript file:

```
function output() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("PO");
    var y = Number(x.elements["entry"]);
    var g = y.toString();
    document.write(g);
}
```

I'm well aware of how clunky that javascript is I just wanted to make sure everything was being done properly.

Comment: Where are you attaching the `output()` function to an event listener?

Comment: Side note, one letter variable names are great for reducing bandwidth, but TERRIBLE for readability and maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really quickly, I feel like we should talk about the top half of your code. Realistically you only use the CDN's when you are trying to quickly add something for testing. Even jQuery will tell you not to link to their files in a production environment because you never know when their server will go down or be flooded with requests. Include your own copy of jQuery -- it's sort of why you downloaded it in the first place. Also, avoid `document.write()`, you'll like yourself a lot more for it. If you need to check the value of something but don't want to add it to the document, use `console.log` and check your browser's developer's console.

```
<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 In production, it is NOT recommended to use this. 
<script>
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
   just include the local version of jQuery automatically. -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/server_browse.js"></script>
```

Next thing is the fact that you include jQuery, but then *never* use it. jQuery, while being a fairly compact library, is still extra script the browser must load in order to go forward. If you aren't going to use it, then get rid of it. If you are going to use it, then let's make sure we are using it correctly.

Lastly, you have this output function, which isn't attached to anything as far as I can tell. I don't see a single location where you have instructed the browser to run the function whenever.

Here is what I would do for this snippet we've been given.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#PO :submit').on('click', function(e) {
    //Normally I would use $('#PO').on('submit'...
    //But the sandbox model doesn't allow for that to work correctly. So, we are using this.
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    //Notation I use to have the jQuery object and regular object of this event;
    var value = $this.siblings('[name="entry"]');
    //If using this function from the form, this line would change to 
    //var value = $this.find('[name="entry"]');
    $('#results').html("Input value: " + value.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="PO" action="js/server_browse.js">
  PO:
  <input name="entry" type="number">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

### Without jQuery

If you wanted to get the same results but without using jQuery (even though you include it):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var element = document.getElementById('PO-submit');
  //When not using a snippet, change to document.getElementById('PO');

  element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //change to element.addEventListener('submit',... 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.cancelBubble = true;

    var result_div = document.getElementById('results');
    //Get the HTMLElement for the results ID element.

    var form_input = this.form.elements['entry'];
    //Change to this.elements['entry'];

    result_div.innerHTML = 'Results :' + form_input.value;

  });



});
```

```html
<form id="PO">
  PO:
  <input name="entry" type="number">
  <input id="PO-submit" type="submit">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Accessing the element

1. `getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like *list* of elements, not a single element
2. `PO` is not a tag name, the tag name is `form`
3. `PO` is the **id**, use `getElementById`

## Getting the value

An HTML element object is not the value of that object. You need to access the `.value` property

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("PO");
    var y = x.elements["entry"].value;
    var g = y.toString();
    document.write(g);`
so am I supposed to get that element and turn it into a value like I've done there?

Comment: <code> doesn't work in comments. Surround them with `